# Docker containers missing on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04

I fired up my Ubuntu 20.04 Virtual Machine today and sadly my docker containers seem to be gone. Running `docker ps -a` is a blank list. I'm not sure what may have caused this event, so I need some help troubleshooting. Recently, I was testing out docker-compose which I ran apt install docker-compose on my machine if that could have caused any issues. I also recently did a `apt update` / `apt upgrade` as well.

I don't see any files in /var/lib/docker/containers or /volumes if that's where my data should be. If they're gone oh well, but I'd like to try to figure out what happened so it doesn't happen again.

Comment: have you tried "docker container ls" or "docker image ls"? Since you upgraded, it's possible your docker installation was updated, so all containers have been stopped/removed and the state has been reset.

Comment: I mean "docker container ls --all" Your volumes, images and containers should still be there. Installation of docker-compose should make no difference.

Comment: docker container ls --all returns an empty list.

Comment: Append the history of docker commands you have run.

Comment: It's a bit late to be saying this if you've already lost your data, but you really shouldn't be storing important data in containers anyway. Either use docker volumes or map your working dir to your host. Containers are designed to be ephemeral. And, docker-compose is part of docker now, so you didn't have to install docker-compose as a separate thing.

Comment: I don't have a full history of commands unless there is a way to see those in linux. I did have my dockers mapped to volumes if there would be a to round those up and restore the images to them, however I'm not finding those either

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.